# Insert in middle of list

Tags: java, collections

I have a list of elements that contain for example `abc`. To produce the document `aXbc`, i insert `X` at position 1. However, the list take `abc` as one element, so the position 1 is in reality position 4 in the content of my list. So, my question is, how can i insert in the middle of this list and produce `aXbc` directly ? of course i can browse the list and `concat` each element ... ! but there are not in java a structure that make this directly ?

```
list.add("abc");
list.add(1, "X");
```

Want `aXbc`

Comment: You are trying to insert middle of String.

Comment: Can you give a more complex example describing the state of the list before and after the insert operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having a list of strings. One thing to keep in mind is that `String` is immutable: once it exists you cannot change it, you can only overwrite it with a new value.

The best course of action would be to create a new string:

```
String value = "abc";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.append(value.subString(0, 1));
sb.append("X");
sb.append(value.subString(1, value.length()));
```

If you really want to use a list:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value = "abc";

    List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for(char c : value.toCharArray()){
        characters.add(c);
    }

    characters.add(1, 'X');
    System.out.println(characters);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(char c : characters){
        sb.append(c);
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Output:

> [a, X, b, c]
>   aXbc

This will create a new list of characters based on the characters in your given string.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing elements in a `List` and chars in a `String`. If you want to insert characters or Strings in the middle of another String, use a `StringBuilder`.

Of course you could create a List of `Characters`, if you're set on using a `List`.

Comment: He's not confusing them---he's *asking* how to make it work without manually iterating and concatting each element.

Comment: Well Marko, he's saying "However, the list take abc as one element, so the position 1 is in reality position 4 in the content of my list." and that sounds to me like confusion about what Lists are.

Comment: He is also saying "of course i can browse the list and concat each element ... ! but there are not in java a structure that make this directly ?" which sounds to me like he knows what he's talking about, even if he hasn't expressed himself in the clearest manner.

Comment: This looks rather like a comment, not the answer... at least for me.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks about your answer, but as Marko  says, i want to use a collection if it is possible

Comment: Well, then use a List of Characters like I said.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like

```
list.add(1, new StringBuilder(list.get(1)).insert(somePosition, "someString").toString());
```

That means getting the string at the position of list  and inserting some string at required position , and putting it back at same `position`.

Answer (score 0):

You need `list.set(index,Element)` method. `add` method will append new element to `List`.

```
 list.set(1, new StringBuilder(list.get(1)).insert(1, "X").toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a specialized list of strings which allows the transformation of all members by inserting characters into them.

There is definitely no Java class with such specialized behavior, and neither have I heard of anything in well-knows public libraries.

The closest match to what you are looking for would be a function-oriented API which would allow a `map` transformation of the list with the mapping function transforming input string into output string by inserting characters.

Google Guava library supports such function-oriented list operations. Also, check out the by-now quite stable Java 8 Early Access, which has this built-in.

Answer (score 0):

do like this.

```
int index= list.indexOf("abc"); // Getting the position of the object.
if(index != -1){    
    String newString = new StringBuffer("abc").insert(1,"X").toString();// Modifying  the object
    list.set(index, newString ); //Updating the object in same position.
}
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer would work so that others can learn from your answer.